# Vite + Typescript: how to import from root directory?

Tags: typescript, vite

If I have a folder, "functions" in the project root directory, with an exported function (in a file, `oneFunction.tsx`):

```
export function myFunc() {
    const thing = 'Some text';
    return thing;
}
```

and I try to import this in a component like this:

```
import {myFunc} from '/functions/oneFunction';
```

It almost works in development, I can use the function, but I get a typescript error:

```
Cannot find module '/functions/oneFunction' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

And it won't compile if I run `yarn build`.

If I remove the slash: `{myFunc} from 'functions/oneFunction';` , the typecript error disappears but there is a compilation error:

```
Failed to resolve import "functions/oneFunction"
```

So I am wondering how do imports from the root directory?

I have path alias for the "src" folder which works, but I didn't succeed in creating an alias for the root.

I tried this in tsconfig:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"],
  "#root/*": [ "." ]
}
```

and in vite.config:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
    '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    "#root": resolve(__dirname),
    },
  },
```

(also installed `@types/node` and `"types": ["node"]` to tsconfig)

But it doesn't work: `import {myFunc} from '#root/functions/oneFunction';`

**Update**

Here is a [reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-vite-react-ts-path-alias-in-vite-config?file=src%2Fpages%2FHome.tsx,functions%2FsomeFunc.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2FSomeComp.tsx)

**Update**

If I try the same thing on a different project without typescript, I can use the import that starts with a slash with no problem, and it builds ( `import {myFunc} from '/functions/oneFunction';` )

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the reason is path in tsconfig: `"#root/*": ["./*"]`

Here's a solution that works for me for both src and root aliases

tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    "#root/*": ["./*"]
  }
},
```

vite.config:

```
// import { resolve } from 'path';

resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    '#root': resolve(__dirname)
  }
},
```

Comment: For me it didn't work though. I added a link to a reproduction.

Comment: There's still the error in .tsconfig file in the reproduction example. You need to add alias exactly in this way, as I mentioned above
`"#root/*": ["./*"]`. Here is the fork of the reproduction with fix: [link to fixed reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-vite-react-ts-path-alias-in-vite-config-cxpnzh?file=src%2Fpages%2FHome.tsx,tsconfig.node.json,tsconfig.json)

Comment: But in the fork you made, if I uncomment "SomeFunc" or "SomeComp" in the Home component, it still fails ("Failed to resolve import")?

Comment: There is indeed an error, I was unable to make ts work with this config. However, a solution I found is to use `"paths": { "/*": ["./*"] }` alongside the given vite config.